# Scroll SlickGrid only one line, when using keyboard navigation

Tags: slickgrid

I have implemented a slickgrid and activated keyboard navigation.
When the users is scrolling down using the down-arrow key and reaches the last of the currently visible rows, the grid loads a whole new section of rows and places the selection at the top.

My user tests have all included a complaint about this behaviour as they all find the jump jarring.

I would like to implement behaviour, so the grid scrolls just one line at a time, when I press the down arrow while the last visible row is selected.

I was wondering if there might be some setting, I have overlooked, or if anyone has some suggestions for how to approach the task of adding this behaviour.

(the "problem" is the same, when you scroll upwards - only reversed of course)

Comment: Like @Tin said below, the behavior you're looking for would be very inefficient since the entire grid would have to be invalidated and re-rendered each time.

Comment: how do you activate keyboard navigation?

Comment: @gabodev77 Well it's been a while, but I think "activated keyboard navigation" was perhaps a slight exaggeration. Keyboard navigation with arrow keys is the default - all I really did, as I recall, was do a `grid.gotoCell(0,0)` to focus the first cell, and the arrow keys just worked.

Comment: @KimChristensen I saw the documentation and I see a grid option call: enableCellNavigation, if true you can natigate with tab and directions key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is controlled by the `doPaging` argument in `scrollRowIntoView(row, doPaging)` (https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/blob/master/slick.grid.js#L2662).  There's no setting to control that behavior, but you could easily add one.

It was initially written this way to make keyboard navigation faster since continuously navigating down doesn't have to do as much work as it would have if we were updating the grid on every 'row down'.

Comment: Thank you very much!
I'll do some testing, to determine if the performance hit is too big to make it worh it.